# Antonym of syllogism?

Tags: antonyms, suffixes

"deduction" is a synonym of "syllogism". "induction" is an antonym of "deduction"

I was wondering if there is a antonym of "syllogism" which share the same suffix as "syllogism"?

Comment: A *syllogism* is a type of *deduction*, the two words are not synonyms, and *induction* is not an antonym for either. In fact, you can even use the syllogism form in an inductive argument.  The question, as asked, is based on incorrect assumptions.

Comment: I would suggest 'synthesism' as the word that fits your requirements to the tee, although there is no such entry in the OED. The word 'synthesis' does carry the meaning of induction in various contexts in logic and philosophy. That said I would stick to 'induction' when I mean induction.

Comment: @ChrisSunami: induction is from specific to general, and deduction is from general to specific. Right?

Comment: That definition of induction and deduction is well-known, but it doesn't match the current usage, please see here: http://www.iep.utm.edu/ded-ind/ . Since there are technical terms, it's probably best to stick with the technical definitions.  Sorry if this seems pedantic --I used to teach logic.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because its first two lines are misinformation. Tim: please remove them, and I'll undo my downvote.

Comment: @ChrisSunami: what else besides syllogism belong to deduction?

Comment: Logical terms are being mixed with etymology and great abandon here. Don't forget that _synonym_ and _antonym_ are logical terms, too. +1 for suggesting a _-logism_ libfix, although I'm not sure philosophy is ready for that yet.

Comment: A _syllogism_ is not abstract like _deduction_, but rather one of a set of fixed linguistic forms for stating logical deductions. [Medieval logicians](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-LogicalNotation.pdf) recognized twenty-four (out of 256) modes of [the syllogism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism) as being valid, and even gave them mnemonic names. _Barbara, Celarent, Darii, Ferio, Barbarix, Feraxo; Cesare, Festino, Camestres, Baroco, Camestrop, Cesarox;_ etc.). All of them have different kinds of "antonyms", depending.

Comment: @Tim Wikipedia has good articles on induction and deduction --I checked them before posting to confirm my info.  Also, the philosophy stack exchange has a number of good logicians on it, although in this case they'd probably also direct you to wikipedia.

Comment: What do you mean by *antonym* of syllogism? An illogical argument? Or are you simply looking for synonyms for *induction*?

Answer (score 2):

Lewis Carroll provides the answer in ‘Sylvie and Bruno’:

> For a complete logical argument, we need two prim Misses –
>
> And they produce – A delusion.
>
> But what is the whole argument called?
>
> A Sillygism.

Comment: I was asking for a synonym of induction.

Comment: I can't really upvote this answer but you get a mental +1 from me for the Syvie and Bruno reference!

Comment: @Tim. Oh yeh, but I couldn' resist.

Answer (score 1):

"Sophism" would be the antonym, which the *OED* defines as:

> A specious but fallacious argument, either used deliberately in order to deceive or mislead, or employed as a means of displaying ingenuity in reasoning.